# Multiline truncate movement

Tags: css, multiline, truncate, ellipsis

I'm getting an interesting render bug. When I put `width` and `margin: auto` on the parent element then resize the browser. Tada!!! dots are moving.

Moving truncate
https://codepen.io/hamzaerbay/pen/YQRLep?editors=1100

Normal behavior 
https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: interesting behaviour, as soon as the h2 is inside a div the ellipsis moves with the resizing. Any special reason you need to place it inside a div? If you don't need to absolutely rely on CSS, have a look at clamp.js (https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) does the job for you quite well - cross browser

Comment: This is a sample. I m using that on the card and using a lot of cards at the same time. So I have fix with css. Can't use the 3rd party js.